# Using username and password to authenticate wcf service users

Tags: wcf, web-services, authentication

I have added a WCF service to an existing ASP.NET website which is hosted on IIS. The users of this service are my registered users with their credentials stored in my SQL Server database.  I simply want username and password to authenticate valid users before providing the data through WCF service. I have gone through a lot of links and text on the web but I am not able to grasp the things given on Authentication and Authorization except adding to my confusion. I am not using HTTPS and certificate in initial phase.

I want a simple solution where users of the service will pass username and password with every call to the API. I will receive these credentials, validate against my SQL server database and serve XML/JSON data accordingly. The API calls will be from browser or mobile clients in the form of AJAX/JQuery. If possible I want the clients pass the credentials in HTTP headers instead of query string and on the server side I retrieve user credentials from HTTP headers.

Simple approach with any example would be appreciated.

Please note that I am not an expert in .NET development or web services.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Go for WCF REST. Its easy.

Comment: Hi Faizan thanks! I am using WCF REST. Can you please explain how to pass username password and retrieving the same in service.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable input Faizan! I have successfully added the Authorization header in http request using Ajax/JQuery from client html file and also retrieved the user credentials on wcf side. Now one more question comes to mind, is there any method in wcf side to know if user has not provided authorization header and automatically send 401, and not processing the request further.

Answer (score 0):

ok! This is **GET** method although it is strongly not recommended to send Username and Password in query string but to give you starter you can use it.

Define your contract as:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyService
{        
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/username={username}&password={password}",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.XML,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
    string MyMethod(string username, string password);        
}
```

And in your implementation method, you can retrieve same username and password.

```
public class MyServiceImpl:IMyService
{
    public string MyMethod(string username, string password)
    {
        return "You entered "+username +" and "+password; // This will returned as an XML.
    }
}
```

Change your *Web.Config* like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration> 
  <appSettings>        
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />       
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="2147483647" executionTimeout="300"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="" name="Namespace.MyService">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="RESTBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="webHttpBG" contract="Namespace.Name.IMyService" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:51855/MyService.svc" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
      <bindings>
          <webHttpBinding>
              <binding name="webHttpBG" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
    maxBufferPoolSize="21474836470" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
                receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00">
                  <security mode="None"/>
              </binding>                  
      </webHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="RESTBehavior">
      <webHttp helpEnabled="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<protocolMapping>
    <add binding="webHttpBinding" scheme="http" bindingConfiguration="webHttpBG" />
</protocolMapping>    
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"  />
```

And for testing, you can use Browser. Type url defined in Web.Config file. For example

```
http://localhost:51855/MyService.svc/username=myname&password=123
```

When you will type this url on browser and hit enter it will call your "**MyMethod**" provided that Service is running.

You can also use Fiddler for testing your service.

Comment: Thank you so much Faizan! Can I pass username and password via http header kind of.., as I have more query string parameters for filtering data. If yes, then how to pass and retrieve the same in service. Thanks.

Comment: See this for setting headers http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg258441(v=vs.110).aspx and you can get headers in WCF Method using IncomingWebRequestContext request = WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest;
WebHeaderCollection headers = request.Headers;